# How do I use JavaScript to turn this data into a daily high and a daily low?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have many months of data in this format from a sensor taken every 10 minutes:

```
2/18/2020 1:33:09 PM 20.3 C
2/18/2020 1:43:09 PM 20.2 C
2/18/2020 1:53:10 PM 20.3 C
2/18/2020 2:03:10 PM 20.2 C
2/18/2020 2:13:10 PM 20.4 C
```

I used VS Code and RegEx to pare it down to this format:

```
18,20.3
18,20.2
18,20.3
18,20.2
18,20.4
```

Something tells me it should be really simple to use JS Arrays and a for loop to create this format:

```
Day 18: High 20.4 Low 20.2
(And rest of the month)
```

Obviously I'm a JS beginner, but it's the language I'm the most familiar with as I've used it some for web development on some small projects. Any input is appreciated, even just a kick in the right direction!

Comment: Yes this can be done with javascript, but you're going to need to get the data in some kind of reusable format, like an array of objects that looks like `[{day: 18, temp: 20.3}, {day: 18, temp: 20.4}, ...]` in order to be able to do that.

Comment: a simple for loop should with some `if (v<low) { low=v; } else if (v>hight) { high = v }` should work just fine?

Comment: If you can get your month data into an array (eg `[20.3, 20.2, 20.3, ...]`), you can use those directly in [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with 3 loops, one to parse the data, one to collect each day's temps into an array, and one to print the high/low temps for each day.

```js
let str = `18,20.3
18,20.2
18,20.3
18,20.2
18,20.4`;
let lines = str.split("\n").map(line => line.split(",").map(parseFloat));
let days = [];
for (let [day, temp] of lines) {
    if (!days[day]) {
        days[day] = [];
    }
    days[day].push(temp);
}
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    if (days[i]) {
        console.log(`Day ${i}: High ${Math.max(...days[i])} Low ${Math.min(...days[i])}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply so quickly, I'm going to chug away at this tonight and reply back. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you already used RegExp to bring it down to that format you may rewrite it, so bring it into JSON-Format. Use Javascript regular expressions or an editor to use this RE:

```
search for /\d{1,2}\/(\d{1,2})\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:AM|PM) (-?\d+\.\d) C/
replace with {"day":\1, "temp":\2},
```

With some fixes like removing the last comma and adding surrounding `[]` around the whole filecontent, you end up with a JSON like this.

```
[{"day":18, "temp":20.3},
{"day":18, "temp":20.2},
{"day":18, "temp":20.3},
{"day":18, "temp":20.2},
{"day":18, "temp":20.4}]
```

Using `var arr = JSON.parse( filecontentString )` will give you an array of objects on which you may access the data.

```
b ='[{"day":18, "temp":20.3},\
{"day":18, "temp":20.2},\
{"day":18, "temp":20.3},\
{"day":18, "temp":20.2},\
{"day":18, "temp":20.4}]';

arr = JSON.parse(b);
var min = max = arr[0].temp;
var result = "";
var i = 1;
for (; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // still in the same day, compare values
    if( arr[i-1].day == arr[i].day && i < arr.length) {
        min = Math.min(arr[i].temp, min);
        max = Math.max(arr[i].temp, max);
    }
    else {
        // we reach this code at new day
        // print day's min/max
        result = result + "Day "+arr[i].day+": High "+max+" Low "+min+"\n";
        // reset for the new date
        min = max = arr[i].temp;
    }
}
// for the last entry
result = result + "Day "+arr[arr.length-1].day+": High "+max+" Low "+min+"\n";
```